# Django does not have access to environment variable

Tags: django, environment-variables

I want to deploy my Django site to DigitalOcean App Platform so I copy the settings from their official sample app (https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-django/blob/main/mysite/settings.py).

And here's the problematic part:

```
...
import os
...
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

if os.getenv('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT_MODE', 'False') == 'True':
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
elif len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[1] != 'collectstatic':
    if os.getenv('DATABASE_URL', None) is None:
        raise Exception('DATABASE_URL environment variable is not set')
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')),
    }
```

When I fire up the development server, I get this error:

```
...
    raise Exception('DATABASE_URL environment variable is not set')
Exception: DATABASE_URL environment variable is not set
```

**This tells me the `if` statement is evaluated to `False` even though I have this environment variable:**

[image]

I create a same `System` variable:

[image]

But I get the same error.

Now I go to Python shell and test this:

```
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT_MODE', 'False') == 'True')
True
>>> print(os.getenv('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT_MODE'))
True
>>>
```

The environment variable looks fine.

At this point I go back to `settings.py` and edit the `if` statement like this:

```
...
if str(os.getenv('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT_MODE', 'False')) == 'True':
...
```

And I get the exact same error again.

So, Django has no access to `DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT_MODE` variable and this is what I can't figure out how to resolve.

P.S:
I can't use `python-dotenv` package here so I haven't tested it. Also please note that I'm on a Windows machine.